# Show image from image url in buffer

Tags: images

It seems like this should be pretty straightforward since Emacs knows how to display images.

In a buffer, let's say I have a URL to an image like:

`http://centre.nikkeiplace.org/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/aikido11.jpg`

I'd like to put the caret on that url, call a function like `expand-image-from-url` and have it render the image in-line.

Is this something that's easily possible?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you don't mind the image being displayed in a different buffer, just do

```
M-x ffap
```

If you insist on the image appearing in the current buffer, you'll need to do just a little more work:

```
(require 'url)

(defun insert-image-from-url (&optional url)
  (interactive)
  (unless url (setq url (url-get-url-at-point)))
  (unless url
    (error "Couldn't find URL."))
  (let ((buffer (url-retrieve-synchronously url)))
    (unwind-protect
         (let ((data (with-current-buffer buffer
                       (goto-char (point-min))
                       (search-forward "\n\n")
                       (buffer-substring (point) (point-max)))))
           (insert-image (create-image data nil t)))
      (kill-buffer buffer))))
```

Comment: That's the thing, I want it displayed inline in the same buffer.

Comment: You're a tough customer.  Edited with some sample code.

Comment: Very nice! One thing to note: I had to grab some of the 'thingatpt' packages to get it to work. I suppose url-get-url-at-point is not a built-in command.

Comment: You just need `(require 'url)`.

Comment: Thank you!  Works perfectly.